# Embed picture in a CommandButton via vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to programatically create a button and add an image embedded into it. From what I could investigate, a standard Button object (or "Form Button") cannot help me as it has less formatting options, so I have to go for the CommandButton option.

After some investigation, I came up to the following code:

```
Dim OLEbtn As Object
Set OLEbtn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=n(0), Top:=n(1), Width:=55, Height:=25)

OLEbtn.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\myfile.png")
```

However, I am getting a *error 481: Invalid image* with this last line.

If I try with a different image, as a jpg, I get the *error 438: Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method* instead.

Can anyone provide any insights as on why?

I dont know how I can provide with the images I am trying to load, but if you consider them needed, I'm more than happy to show them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I was trying to set a property that only existed on a sub-object named "Object", and thus the failing!

```
OLEbtn.Object.Picture = LoadPicture(pic)
```

Made the trick!

However, I've noticed png images are not accepted in any case, proceeding with jpg for now, but it would be great if someone knew why png is rejected...!

Cheers